# Pandas: Apply function over each pair of columns under constraints

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

As the title says, I'm trying to apply a function over each pair of columns of a dataframe under some conditions. I'm going to try to illustrate this. My df is of the form:

```
Code |  14  |  17  |  19  | ...
w1   |  0   |   5  |   3  | ...
w2   |  2   |   5  |   4  | ... 
w3   |  0   |   0  |   5  | ...
```

The Code corresponds to a determined location in a rectangular grid and the ws are different words. I would like to apply cosine similarity measure between each pair of columns only **(EDITED!)** **if the sum of items in one of the columns of the pair is greater thah 5**.

The desired output would be something like:

```
     | [14,17]  |  [14,19]  |  [14,...]  |  [17,19]  | ...
Sim  |cs(14,17) |cs(14,19)  |cs(14,...)  |cs(17,19)..| ...
```

cs is the result of the cosine similarity for each pair of columns.
Is there any suitable method to do this?

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: If I'm getting it straight, you wouldn't want `cs(14,17)` nor `cs(14,19)` etc. because there's no item in the '14' column that's greater than 5. And did you try anything? Could you please provide some code and examples that failed?

Comment: Hi, @danielhadar. Actually so far I've done few calculations by hand. I'm asking if is there any method to apply functions (cosine similarity in this case, but I will apply more functions) to each pair of columns in a vectorial way, i.e without writing loops over columns. The build of the last df is only to have a better visualization of the result, but it's not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply the cosine metric to each pair from two collections of inputs, you
could use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist). This will be much much faster than
using a double Python loop.

Let one collection be all the columns of `df`. Let the other collection be only those columns where the sum is greater than 5:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'14':[0,2,0], '17':[5,5,0], '19':[3,4,5]})
mask = df.sum(axis=0) > 5
df2 = df.loc[:, mask]
```

Then all the cosine similarities can be computed with one call to `cdist`:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as SSD
values = SSD.cdist(df2.T, df.T, metric='cosine')
# array([[  2.92893219e-01,   1.11022302e-16,   3.00000000e-01],
#        [  4.34314575e-01,   3.00000000e-01,   1.11022302e-16]])
```

The values can be wrapped in a new DataFrame and reshaped:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=df.columns, index=df2.columns)
result = result.stack()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.spatial.distance as SSD
df = pd.DataFrame({'14':[0,2,0], '17':[5,5,0], '19':[3,4,5]})
mask = df.sum(axis=0) > 5
df2 = df.loc[:, mask]
values = SSD.cdist(df2.T, df.T, metric='cosine')
result = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=df.columns, index=df2.columns)
result = result.stack()
mask = result.index.get_level_values(0) != result.index.get_level_values(1)
result = result.loc[mask]
print(result)
```

yields the Series

```
17  14    0.292893
    19    0.300000
19  14    0.434315
    17    0.300000
```